# Apply function with arguments across Multiindex levels

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I would like to apply a custom function to each level within a multiindex.
For example, I have the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4,4)),
               columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['OP','PK'],['PRICE','QTY']]))
```

of which I want to add a column for each level 0 column, called "Value" which is the result of the following function;

```
def my_func(df, scale):
     return df['QTY']*df['PRICE']*scale
```

where the user supplies the "scale" value.

Even in setting up this example, I am not sure how to show the result I want. But I know I want the final dataframe's multiindex column to be

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['OP','PK'],['PRICE','QTY','Value']]))
```

Even if that wasn't had enough, I want to apply one "scale" value for the "OP" level 0 column and a different "scale" value to the "PK" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
def my_func(df, scale):
     #select second level of columns
     df1 = df.xs('QTY', axis=1, level=1).values *df.xs('PRICE', axis=1, level=1) * scale
     #create MultiIndex in columns 
     df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['val']])
     #join to original
     return pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

print (my_func(df, 10))
     OP              PK          
  PRICE QTY   val PRICE QTY   val
0     0   1     0     2   3    60
1     4   5   200     6   7   420
2     8   9   720    10  11  1100
3    12  13  1560    14  15  2100
```

EDIT:

For multiple by scaled values different for each level is possible use list of values:

```
print (my_func(df, [10, 20]))

     OP              PK          
  PRICE QTY   val PRICE QTY   val
0     0   1     0     2   3   120
1     4   5   200     6   7   840
2     8   9   720    10  11  2200
3    12  13  1560    14  15  4200
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, any ideas if I wanted to use a different "scale" value for the "OP"/"PK" columns?

Comment: @ShaunH - Do you want multiple  each colum and then sum? Can you explain more?

Comment: I just meant I might want to use a "scale" value of 10 for just the "OP" column, and maybe a "scale" value of 20 for the "PK" column. So the ["OP","val"] column is [0,200,720,1560] and the ["PK","val"] is [120,840,2200,4200]

Comment: I was thinking I could somehow provide a list of scale values, where the length of the list is equal to the length of the level 0 column. E.g. [10, 20]. But I don't know how to work this into the function

Comment: @ShaunH - You need use `print (my_func(df, np.array([10, 20])))`

Comment: @ShaunH - Also working `print (my_func(df, [10, 20]))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + `agg`, and then concatenate the pieces together with `pd.concat`.

```
scale = 10
v = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.prod(1) * scale) 
v.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([v.columns, ['value']])

pd.concat([df, v], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)

     OP              PK          
  PRICE QTY value PRICE QTY value
0     0   1     0     2   3    60
1     4   5   200     6   7   420
2     8   9   720    10  11  1100
3    12  13  1560    14  15  2100
```